# Kivy - Make buttons change the text of TextInput?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an app with 3 buttons and a display (which I'm using TextInput for).

When a button is pressed, I want the text of the button to be shown in the dispaly. e.g, if you press 1 1 2, I want 112 to show up in the display.

Is there a way to do this without adding on_press to every single button manually? Here's the code that isn't working. I think it doesn't work because "self.ids.textbox.text" is referring to the wrong thing. I'm not sure how to correct this.

Not working main2.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Buttons(Button):

    def callback(self, text):
        self.ids.textbox.text = "Hi"


class Main2Widget(BoxLayout):

    pass

class Main2App(App):
    '''docstring for Main2App'''
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 200)
        return Main2Widget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main2App().run()
```

Not working main2.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<Buttons>:
    on_press: root.callback(self.text)

<Main2Widget>:
    id: mainapp

    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: textbox
        multiline: False
        readonly: True

        hint_text: "I'm an input box!"
        font_size: 20

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Buttons:
            id: btn1
            text: "1"

        Buttons:
            id: btn2
            text: "2"

        Buttons:
            id: btn3
            text: "3"
```

If I do this, it works:

Working main2.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Main2Widget(BoxLayout):

    def callback(self, text):
        self.ids.textbox.text += text

    pass

class Main2App(App):
    '''docstring for Main2App'''
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 200)
        return Main2Widget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main2App().run()
```

Working main2.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<Main2Widget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: textbox
        multiline: False
        readonly: True

        hint_text: "I'm an input box!"
        font_size: 20

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button:
            id: btn1
            text: "1"
            on_press: root.callback(self.text)

        Button:
            id: btn2
            text: "2"
            on_press: root.callback(self.text)

        Button:
            id: btn3
            text: "3"
            on_press: root.callback(self.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `root` referrs to the root of the current rule (`<Buttons>` in this case).  The root of the rule also contains the ids contained within that rule, so the function is called on `Buttons`, but since it has no ids, `self.ids` is empty.

In your second example, `root` refers to `<Main2Widget>`, which does contain a widget in it's rule with an id of `textbox`.

In general, a widget rule (`<Buttons>`) cannot access widgets outside of its own rule.  This is because it can be inserted anywhere and may or may not have anything to access.

The exception is the `App` object.  You can access your application object anywhere in kv.

I can think of 3 workarounds for your problem.  The simplest is to put the function call in the `<Main2Widget>` rule (which you tried).  If you really want a separate rule for the buttons, than the second option is to put the `callback` function in  your `App` class, and call `app.callback`.  Then you can just keep a reference to your root widget:

```
class Main2App(App):
    '''docstring for Main2App'''    
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 200)
        self.root =  Main2Widget()
        return self.root

    def callback(self, text):
        self.root.ids.textbox.text = "Hi"
```

The last, and one I would probably use, is to utilize a `StringProperty` (also on the `App` class):

```
class Main2App(App):
    '''docstring for Main2App'''
    the_text = StringProperty()
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 200)
        return Main2Widget()
```

Then you can bind the textinput to the property with `text: app.the_text` and set it in the button with `on_press: app.the_text = self.text`.  This is cleaner in my opinion because you don't need to use a callback or access the ids on the python side.